# Ceiling Fan Tripping breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, ceiling-fan

I installed a new fan. Since I will be controlling the fan and light from the unit itself, I changed the existing fan controller on the wall to a 15/20 amp on/off switch.
Going to the wall controller from the house were two black wires and I put those on the two gold connections of the on/off switch.
The fan is wired:
1 black from house, 1 bl. Fr.fan, 1 bl.fr. light and 1 bluefr. fan.
1 White from House, 1 We. Fr.fan, 1 wh. Fr. Light.
1 green from mounting bracket, 1 Gr. Fr. Fan, 1 copper fr. house
What did I wire wrong? This is how the instructions said to do it.

To clarify...3 black and 1 blue together, 3 white together and 2 green and 1 copper together.

Comment: Gonna need pix of fan and switch box. Something funny is going on.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of the fan and switch boxes?

Comment: Is there a remote with this device?

Comment: No remote. Not wanting to keep you kind people thinking I’m ignoring you but it will be a while before I can do photos. My dad is dying and I’m spending most of my time with him. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: Best of luck, that's  a hard one.

Comment: Since my last post I have reworked some things and tried to eliminate possible problems. Going into the switch on the wall are two black wires, one hot and one is the traveler wire. I eliminated the second wall switch so I don’t see the need for this wire except to complete a circuit. I may have the wrong switch and that will be my next thing to replace. I replaced a ceiling fan switch with a 15/20 amp 2 pole toggle switch. I wired my fan for a toggle switch and not a ceiling fan switch. The switch that is on the wall at present is the two pole switch with two black wires going into it.

Comment: I do not know how to add photos.

Comment: It has been resolved. Thank you for your input.